# Staying in navigation drawer when clicking item from it

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigaiton drawer. When i click on a certain item from the nav drawer, the nav drawer is closed and is redirected to main page. I want navigation drawer to refresh after clicking an item in it.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (id == R.id.refresh_drawer) {
        ----CODE----

    } 
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

What can i do to make nav drawer refresh and not redirect to main page? somebody please help me

Comment: comment the closeDrawer() line

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This worked perfectly like i needed

Answer (score 0):

It closes because you used:

```
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

In `onNavigationItemSelected()` method so, removing this will help.

---

Also:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Define this inside `onCreate()` method and make it private by adding it in above of `onCreate()` like this to have access whole the `Activity`:

```
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
}
```

This is the recommended way to define such widgets inside an `Activity` when `Activity` creates.